# Properties of combining diacritics

Tags: unicode, character-properties

For combining diacritics, are they counted as letters? Since, as far as I know, they can only combine with other letters in well-formed Unicode.

The ICU function to determine if a Unicode codepoint is a letter only takes one codepoint, so for any given codepoint, it can't know if they've been combined with a diacritic- or if it's a diacritic, what it's been combined with. I'm trying to implement something akin to a Unicode-aware regex, using a construct like

```
while(is_letter(codepoint))
```

However, I'm quite concerned about what's going to happen if `codepoint` is actually a diacritic, which would be collated with a previous codepoint, and other collating marks.

Is this safe to do? Or will I have to explicitly find and ignore diacritics and other collating marks?

Edit: What I really need to do is iterate *characters*, not *codepoints*.

This question is a victim of the XY problem. I need to raise a question about my actual *problem*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to do, so I apologize in advance if this isn't the answer you're looking for, but:

> For combining diacritics, are they counted as letters?

Broadly speaking, diacritics are counted as "marks" rather than "letters". For example, U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT, as in <ś>, is a "nonspacing mark", which is one of three kinds of "mark". However, the "modifier letters", which *are* counted as "letters", might nonetheless be thought of as diacritics; for example, U+02C0 MODIFIER LETTER GLOTTAL STOP, as in <sˀ>, is a "modifier letter".

If you look through [the main file of the Unicode Character Database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) (warning: it's 1.3 MB text-file), you can get a sense for which characters are classified as "modifier letters" (`Lm`) and which as "nonspacing marks" (`Mn`) or "spacing marks" (`Ms`) or "enclosing marks" (`Me`).